# Paused BitLocker encryption because no longer want to encrypt the hard drive - how do I get out of encrypting?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker, decryption, pause

I'm hoping someone can help.  I'm not a techy and can't seem to find the same question already answered.

I went to encrypt (using BitLocker) a Buffalo hard drive but after it took about 1 min to reach 0.2% 'encrypted' I decided to pause and eject, thinking this would have ended the encryption process.  However, I had already assigned a password to it on the instruction pre the encryption beginning.  I've since connected my hard drive again and I'm asked to input the password.  If I don't I cannot access the drive.  However, if I do, I CAN access the files but straight away the little BitLocker Drive Encryption dialogue box comes up saying Encryption in progress.. which I have the option to Pause.  So I hit Pause straight away as I do not want to go through with the encryption.  Is there any way I can stop the process and decrypt before encryption is completed?  Or am I forever going to need to Pause quickly and eject.  I fear that will affect my hard drive longer term.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not let it complete? You should be able to remove it afterwards.

Comment: I think you can decrypt the drive by right-clicking on it.  Maybe going to `Properties`  I haven't done it with the GUI in a while.

Answer (score 1):

According to a thread on [a thread on Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/anyone-know-if-its-possible-to-cancel-the/d57b31a8-3f5d-4146-9206-c1c3f571c201), you should be able to select "Decrypt drive", "Turn off BitLocker" or a similar option in the BitLocker control panel.

I'm currently away from my PC and cannot confirm this personally, though.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

[Bitlocker can be managed via command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875513(v=ws.10).aspx)

For example, in my environment we use `manage-bde -protectors -disabled <volume>` to "suspend" a drive and then `manage-bde -protectors -enable <volume>` to "resume" the drive.

To answer your question, you can turn off your drive using `manage-bde -off <volume>` using the command line.  You should receive a prompt detailing the progress of the decryption.