# Can I ever get my Data back?

Tags: external-hard-drive, encryption, data-recovery, bitlocker, disk-encryption

About 2 weeks ago I was doing a decryption to a partition on an External HDD.. - encryption type:(Bitlocker Encryption). But Unfortunately my laptop had shut down during the operation. since then I have tried opening it using every way I know for painstaking 14 days. I have contacted Microsoft Customer Service,Which wasn't helpful at all! and sent me a provoking replay about I should have backed it up! despite that the Bitlocker is a Microsoft service! Is it possible to turn it back? and how this data is my work for 20 years.

Comment: The question is unclear. Were you removing bitlocker from the drive or copying data to an external drive?

Comment: Could you estimate how far along the decryption process had gotten when your laptop failed?

Comment: Insert the External hard drive. Type this command & show us the result: `manage-bde -status <your drive>:` Example `manage-bde -status G:`

Comment: It would really help if you gave us a lot more details about your situation. What exactly were you doing? How were you doing it? What are some of the ways you tried to recover? What went wrong when you tried them?

Comment: Not having a backup is not Microsoft's fault, it's yours, entirely yours. *Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary.* You now know why this is true. If the computer had been destroyed in a house fire would you blame Microsoft?

Answer (score 5):

<sup>This is too long for a comment.</sup>
If the data is valuable, you should **always** backup up the data.

Anyway...., you should be able to resume the process. Once the hard disk/partition is fully decrypted, then you might be able to access the data.

Plug in the external hard drive and try to resume the BitLocker decryption process.
You should also be able to do this by using commands.

```
manage-bde -resume [<Drive>]
manage-bde –resume C:
```

Source: Microsoft
Link: [BitLocker frequently asked questions (FAQ)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-deployment-and-administration-faq#what-happens-if-the-computer-is-turned-off-during-encryption-or-decryption)

> **What happens if the computer is turned off during encryption or decryption?**
>
> If the computer is turned off or goes into hibernation, the BitLocker
>   encryption and decryption process will resume where it stopped the
>   next time Windows starts. This is true even if the power is suddenly
>   unavailable.

Other sources

- [How to Suspend or Resume BitLocker Protection for Drive in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/38508-suspend-resume-bitlocker-protection-drive-windows-10-a.html)
- [How to Enable Suspend/Resume BitLocker Protection for a Drive](https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/enable-suspend-or-resume-bitlocker-protect-for-drive.html)
- https://security.stackexchange.com/q/142785/176981
- [How to resume
  Bitlocker drive encryption paused in Windows 10/8/7?](https://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker-drive-data-recovery/how-to-resume-bitlocker-encryption-paused.html)
- [Paused BitLocker encryption because no longer want to encrypt the hard drive - how do I get out of encrypting?](https://superuser.com/q/766311/485660)
- [Using a Data Recovery Agent to Recover BitLocker-Protected Drives (Windows 7)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ee424312(v%3Dws.10))
- [Using the BitLocker Repair Tool to Recover a Drive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ee523219(v=ws.10))
- [Resumes BitLocker encryption or decryption after it has been paused](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/manage-bde-resume#BKMK_Examples)
- [Resume-BitLocker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/resume-bitlocker?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that deleted data can be destroyed and not recovered. You should be able to identify that the data recovery software has recovered your data before you purchase it. Recover My Files does this by having a file preview window which allows you to view pictures and documents.

Comment: While this is a helpful suggestion, it does not actually make any attempt to answer the actual question, and it comes across as being more of an advertisement for the named software product than anything else. If you have more information that could be added to turn this into a good answer, please us the EDIT button and add this. If this is all you have to add, do not be surprised if this post is downvoted and/of deleted.